# I want to get a Spanish visa but I'm already in Spain

Tags: visas, canada, spain

I am a Canadian travelling to Spain at the moment. I am currently traveling with the 90/180 days visa as a tourist. I fell in love with the beautiful country that is Spain and I would love to extend my stay for some months. The problem is I think I can only ask for a visa if I am in Canada. How can I get a Spanish visa if I am already in Spain?

Thank you!

Comment: What Visa are you wanting to get? Have you thought about a holiday visa? getting a short term Schengen visa will not reset your 90/180 day rule. You could always visit a country outside the Schengen area till your rule resets like the UK or Ireland.

Comment: info on working holiday visa https://anyworkanywhere.com/whv_es.html

Comment: Closing as OP has not answered the questions in comments.